# Render text in a canvas in Flutter with isAntiAlias = false

Tags: flutter, canvas, text, render

Is it possible to render text in a canvas in Flutter with Antialiasing = false?

I need a pixelated text without antialiasing.

I know about

```
Paint()..isAntiAlias = false
```

to draw (for example) a circle without antialiasing.

Is there a way for text rendering too?